# shiny Display HTML entities like &Delta;

Tags: r, shiny

How can I use HTML entities in `shiny`?

The following code shows `&Delta;`, `&#916;` and `&#x0394;` respectively instead of Δ:

```
shinyApp(fluidPage(span("&Delta;", "&#916;", "&#x0394;")), function(...) {})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `shiny` package does not render everything as HTML since it is basically a R package. It takes many features from the `htmltools` package. An example of this would be shiny's `tags` list of function which are the same as the one you can find in the htmltools package.
Try the following:

```r
shinyApp(
  fluidPage(
    span(HTML("&Delta;", "&#916;", "&#x0394;")) # the HTML() function missed
  ),
  function(...) {}
)
```

Comment: Perfekt! +1 That was what I was looking for. Thanks.